# SQLite relationship table

Tags: sqlite

Have a SQLite database where a 28 values are stored every few seconds. The issue I have is that the value is stored in a different table than the table where the variable-name is stored. Now if possible I would like to export the values to for instance Excel so need to query both tables. The id for the value is increased every time the value is stored so needs to have a query that reads every id for a specific variable. However my SQL-knowledge is not good enough so hoping I could get some help here.

The database is built up something like this:
Table 1 (called record)

```
id  valueid  variable
1   1        foo
2   3        bar
3   4        foobar
4   5        foo
5   6        bar
...
```

Table 2 (called value)

```
id  value
1   3.14
3   42
4   123
5   3.1415
6   4242
...
```

So if I would like to read out all foo, it have got the value stored in value-table with id 1, 4 etc (sometimes the valueid increase with 2 instead of 1). Would it be possible to have a SQL-command with something like `SELECT all value FROM (table) value WHERE record.variable = foo`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just join the two tables on the valueid column of the first table and use Where to filter it to only records in table 1 with the value of foo like so:

```
--Select all columns from t2 (value table)
--Join the value table on table 1 using the foreign key column valueid of
--table 1, which is the relationship to the id column of value table
--Using INNER JOIN will only return results where a match is found in value table
--Use the WHERE clause to filter down to only records from table 1 with variable = 'foo'
--You can use AND to add to the conditions of your WHERE clause to filter by date range

SELECT t2.*
FROM record AS t1
INNER JOIN value AS t2
ON t2.[id] = t1.[valueid]
WHERE t1.[variable] = 'foo' AND t2.[TimeStamp] >= someTimeStamp AND t2.[TimeStamp] <= someOtherTimeStamp
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks! Would it be possible to get the values from table 2 in a specific time range? The table record also have a timestamp-column, so if I want 'foo' from between for instance 1541489400000 and 1541503800000 is it possible?

Comment: @Mattias Ok, I updated the answer to show you how to use AND to add to your WHERE clause conditions, in this case to filter by t2 (value table) Timestamp. I hope this has helped you, happy coding.